# Disable a button based on specific date

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a Razor page with a Partial attached. I would like to disable the Create button. Based on Termination Date. if the Termination Date set to after the present day, hovering over 'Create Side Letter' should disable the button, and add a Bootstrap tooltip. Would anyone be able to offer me some assistance as to how best to do this?

```
    @section scripts {
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var lastItem = $(".contractSideLetterPanel:last");
            var clickableTitle = lastItem.children(".panel-heading:first").find("a");

            clickableTitle.click();
        });


    </script>
}

@section additionalStyles {
    @Styles.Render("~/plugins/datatables/media/css/cssDatatables")
}

@section modal {

}

<article class="row">
    <h1 class="pageTitle artistHeader fw200 mb20 mt10">@ViewBag.Title</h1>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-visible" id="sideLettersContainer">
            @* Header *@
            <div class="panel-heading createContentTitle">
                <div class="panel-title createLink">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("CreateSideLetter", "ClientSetup", new
                             {
                                 page = Model.PagingInfo.Page,
                                 take = Model.PagingInfo.Take,
                                 sortBy = Model.PagingInfo.SortPropertyName,
                                 sortAsc = Model.PagingInfo.SortAscending
                             })" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add Side Letter" id="createSideLetterLink">
                        <span class="fa fa-file"></span>&nbsp; Create Side Letter
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            @* body *@
            <div class="panel panel-visible tableContainer mbn">
                @Html.Partial("_SideLettersList", Model)
            </div>

            @* Footer *@
            <div class="panel-footer text-center">
                <a href='@Url.Action("Contracts", "ClientSetup", new
                         {
                             page = Model.PagingInfo.Page,
                             take = Model.PagingInfo.Take,
                             sortBy = Model.PagingInfo.SortPropertyName,
                             sortAsc = Model.PagingInfo.SortAscending,
                             name = Model.SearchModel.Name,
                             createdby = Model.SearchModel.CreatedBy,
                             contractType = Model.SearchModel.ContractType,
                             dateFrom = Model.SearchModel.DateFrom,
                             dateTo = Model.SearchModel.DateTo
                         }
                             )' class="btn btn-primary" id="doneWithSideLettersLink">Done</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

**Partial**

```
<div class="panel-group accordion accordion-lg mbn" id="sideLetterAccordion">
@* Contract Panel *@
@if (Model.OriginalContract != default(ContractDisplayModel))
{
    <div class="panel contractSideLetterPanel mtn">
        <div class="panel-heading sideLetterHeading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle accordion-icon link-unstyled collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sideLetterAccordion" href="#accord1">
                @GetTitle(Model.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo)
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="accord1" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
            <div class="panel-body">
            @* START - Summary Information *@
            @if (Model.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.Description != string.Empty)
            {
                <div class="row">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.Description, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label ptn" })
                    <div class="col-sm-10 form-control-static ptn pb5">
                        <span>@Model.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.Description</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
            <div class="row">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.ContractType, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label ptn" })
                <div class="col-sm-10 form-control-static ptn pb5">
                    @{
                        var contractType = Model.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.ContractType.GetEnumDescription();
                    }
                    <span>@contractType</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.Currency, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label ptn" })
                <div class="col-sm-10 form-control-static ptn pb5">
                    <span>@Model.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.Currency</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.StartDate, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label ptn" })
                <div class="col-sm-4 form-control-static ptn pb5">
                    <span>@Model.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.StartDate.ToString("D")</span>
                </div>
                @if (Model.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.EndDate != default(DateTime?))
                {
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.EndDate, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label ptn" })
                    <div class="col-sm-4 form-control-static ptn pb5">
                        <span>@(Model.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.EndDate != default(DateTime) ? ((DateTime)Model.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.EndDate).ToString("D") : string.Empty)</span>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
            @if (Model.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.SignedDate != default(DateTime?))
            {
                <div class="row">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.SignedDate, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label ptn" })
                    <div class="col-sm-10 form-control-static ptn pb5">
                        <span>@(Model.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.SignedDate != default(DateTime) ? ((DateTime)Model.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.SignedDate).ToString("D") : string.Empty)</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
            @if (Model.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.NotificationDate != default(DateTime?))
            {
                <div class="row">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.NotificationDate, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label ptn" })
                    <div class="col-sm-10 form-control-static ptn pb5">
                        <span>@(Model.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.NotificationDate != default(DateTime) ? ((DateTime)Model.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.NotificationDate).ToString("D") : string.Empty)</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
            @if (Model.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.TerminationDate != default(DateTime?))
            {
                <div class="row">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.TerminationDate, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label ptn" })
                    <div class="col-sm-10 form-control-static ptn pb5">
                        <span>@(Model.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.TerminationDate != default(DateTime) ? ((DateTime)Model.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.TerminationDate).ToString("D") : string.Empty)</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
            @if (Model.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.PostTermCollectionEndDate != default(DateTime?))
            {
                <div class="row">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.PostTermCollectionEndDate, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label ptn" })
                    <div class="col-sm-10 form-control-static ptn pb5">
                        <span>@(Model.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.PostTermCollectionEndDate != default(DateTime) ? ((DateTime)Model.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.PostTermCollectionEndDate).ToString("D") : string.Empty)</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
            @* END - Summary Information *@
```

I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this could be to add a boolean property on your ViewModel called something like TerminationDateHasPassed.

```
public bool TerminationDateHasPassed{ get; set; }
```

Calculate the value for this new property in code behind. Something like:

```
TerminationDateHasPassed = TerminationDate < DateTime.Now
```

In your Partial razor view then you can add the disabled bootsrtap class based on this property to the Create button.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("CreateSideLetter", "ClientSetup", new
                             {
                                 page = Model.PagingInfo.Page,
                                 take = Model.PagingInfo.Take,
                                 sortBy = Model.PagingInfo.SortPropertyName,
                                 sortAsc = Model.PagingInfo.SortAscending
                             })" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip"
title="Add Side Letter" id="createSideLetterLink"
class=@(Model.TerminationDateHasPassed ? "disabled": "")>
                        <span class="fa fa-file"></span>&nbsp; Create Side Letter
                    </a>
```

Comment: Where would I add `TerminationDateHasPassed = TerminationDate < DateTime.Now`

Comment: At the part where you map all the other Model properties... like OriginalContract, PagingInfo etc

Comment: I was going to try `class="@(Model.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.TerminationDate > DateTime.Now) disabled">`

Comment: class="@(Model.OriginalContract.SummaryInfo.TerminationDate > DateTime.Now ? disabled : "")">

Comment: I get the error: CS0103 The name 'disabled' does not exist in the current context

Comment: check how the html is being rendered out, it may be being malformed on quotation marks etc

Comment: So its rendered it: `class="disabled='disabled'" `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176116/discussion-between-fuzzybear-and-rob).